# Linked Profile Plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, plugins, linkedin-api

I tried to create a create at this address:
https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/member-profile

But the script bugs, the profile doesn't appear on roll-over. Here my example:
http://codepen.io/Tchernobil/pen/JGeQez

```
<script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="IN/MemberProfile" data-id="https://www.linkedin.com/in/charles-m%25C3%25A9nard-8702982" data-format="hover" data-related="false"></script>
```

I tried the script in Google Chrome and Firefox, same results. I didn't see any problem in the console.

What is the problem? If LinkedIn is the problem, how can I contact them?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. What helped me:

1. LinkedIn quitely changed the format of the public links. But there is a systematic behind it, so all Links can be recalculated (old to new and even new to old) --> And only the old format works with the plugin.
2. The Plugin did not work on some past FireFox Version. 44.0 works again.

Contacting LinkedIn was useless for me...actually all answers from the LinkedIn Staff was useless.